# Missing data from validated_data in django rest framwork

Tags: django, http, post, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web app and trying to send Post data as **FormData** to a Django Rest Framework Serializer. In the **request.data** I see that all the Post data is there, however after validating and saving the serializer it seems like some of the data did not get passed into **validated_data**.

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(["GET","POST"])
def api_list(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        data = Recipe.objects.all()

        serializer = RecipeSerializer(data, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method=="POST":
        print("POST recieved")
        print (request.data) <----See below
        serializer = RecipeSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("Validating..")
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("validated!")
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print (serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**request.data**

```
<QueryDict: 
{'description': ['"gfdgdfg"'], 
 'name': ['"fdgdfgdf"'], 
 'ingredients': [
     '{"name":"dfgdfg","amount":"gdfgd"}', 
     '{"name":"fdgdfg","amount":"dfgdf"}', 
     '{"name":"dfgdfgdf","amount":"gdfgdf"}'
 ], 
 'directions': [
     '{"content":"gdfgfd"}', 
     '{"content":"gdfgdfg"}', 
     '{"content":"dfgdfdfg"}'
  ], 
'image': [
      <InMemoryUploadedFile: luisana-zerpa-MJPr6nOdppw-unsplash.jpg (image/jpeg)>
 ]
}>
```

**serializer.py**

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ('name', 'amount')

class DirectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Direction
        fields = ('content',)


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    directions = DirectionSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'owner',
            'image',
            'description',
            'created_at',
            'ingredients',
            'directions',
        )


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print (validated_data) <----See Below

        has_ingredients = validated_data.get("ingredients")
        has_directions = validated_data.get("directions")

        if has_ingredients:
            ingredient_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        if has_directions:
            direction_data = validated_data.pop('directions')

        recipe_name = validated_data.get('name')
        recipe_name = recipe_name.replace('"','')

        recipe_description = validated_data.get('description')
        recipe_description = recipe_description.replace('"','')


        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(name=recipe_name, description=recipe_description, image=validated_data.get('image'))
    
        if has_ingredients:
            for ingredient in ingredient_data:
                Ingredient.objects.create(recipe=recipe, name=ingredient.get("name"), amount=ingredient.get("amount"))
        if has_directions:
            for direction in direction_data:
                Direction.objects.create(recipe=recipe, content=direction.get("content"))
        return recipe
```

**validated_data**
*NOTE: I can only get this if I add "required=False" for ingredient and directions else it just return a 404err*

```
{
 'name': '"fdgdfgdf"', 
 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: luisana-zerpa-MJPr6nOdppw-unsplash.jpg (image/jpeg)>, 
 'description': '"gfdgdfg"'
 }
```

I tried looking into overiding the .is_valid() method on the serializers but I couldn't find anything on the official documentation. If I used the Postman app to Post data everything works however whenever I sent data from my frontend this happens. I wonder if I has anything to do with how i'm sending the data but I don't want to include too much unnecessary.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Did you use name attributes for the fields you are not getting the data for?

Comment: what does the `print (serializer.errors)` spit out?

Comment: set `read_only=True` to **directions** and **ingredients **

Comment: @Nealium It gives a 400 error because it can't find ingredients or directions in validated_data. **{'ingredients': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'directions': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Figured out the Answer!

The problem all along was in **how** I was Posting the data.

**Originally** I was sending the post data for "ingredients" and "directions like this"...

```
ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
    formData.append('ingredients',{
        'name':ingredients.name,
        'amount':ingredient.amount
    });
});
```

I had a forEach loop for "directions" as well and it pretty much followed the same pattern.

**The Correct** way to post a List of Objects using multipart/form-data should be like this

```
ingredients.forEach((ingredient, index) => {
        formData.append(`ingredients[${index}]name`, JSON.stringify(ingredient.name));
        formData.append(`ingredients[${index}]amount`, JSON.stringify(ingredient.amount))
    });
```

The difference is that when posting a list we have to detail the the exact path to for each item in the list.

e.g **formData.append(`ingredients[${index}]name`, JSON.stringify(ingredient.name));**

That's about all I know, if anyone has more information on what we need to do that please add on, since there is not much information on why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are forgetting to send the **ingredients** and **directions** to the new **recipe** instance.

This is why your POST endpoint only works when they are not required

You can create the relationship with Recipe after you create the Ingredient instance

```
ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(**inputs)
recipe.ingredient = ingredient
recipe.save()
```

Same goes for Direction:

```
direction = Direction.objects.create(**inputs)
recipe.direction = direction
recipe.save()
```

They were already validated in IngredientSerializer and DirectionSerializer, so you can safely create the relationship with Recipe

**Quick tip:** If you have a flag called **has_ingredients**, you probably mean that you can have recipies without ingredients, in this case, the field should be **required=False**

If you need the ingredients and directions filelds to be required, you will need to create the recipe with all the inputs, for example:

```
recipe = Recipe.objects.create(
    name=recipe_name, 
    description=recipe_description, 
    image=validated_data.get('image'),
    ingredient=ingredient,
    direction=direction
)
```

Another way around: you can create a Recipe instance first with some fields, then add the ingredient and direction and finally call .save() to register the new database entry.

Comment: The issue i'm having is that I'm supposed to create the Ingredient and Directions database entry from the Serializer.py file. So w/o the ingredients data and directions data inside of validated_data prop I can't make the ingredients or directions model instance.

Comment: Try removing the read_only input